# Cannot import Cosmosdb in databricks

Tags: scala, azure-cosmosdb, azure-databricks

I setup a new cluster on databricks which using databricks runtime version 10.1 (includes Apache Spark 3.2.0, Scala 2.12). I also installed azure_cosmos_spark_3_2_2_12_4_6_2.jar in Libraries.

I create a new notebook with Scala

```
import com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark.schema._
import com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark.CosmosDBSpark
import com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark.config.Config
```

But I still get error: object cosmosdb is not a member of package com.microsoft.azure

Does anyone know which step I missing?
Thanks

Comment: Have you seen this article here. May help get you started. https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/cosmos/azure-cosmos-spark_3_2-12/docs/quick-start.md

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the imports you are doing are for the older Spark Connector (https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-spark).

For the Spark 3.2 Connector, you might want to follow the quickstart guides: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/sql/create-sql-api-spark

The official repository is: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/main/sdk/cosmos/azure-cosmos-spark_3-2_2-12

Complete Scala sample: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/cosmos/azure-cosmos-spark_3_2-12/Samples/Scala-Sample.scala

Here is the configuration reference: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/cosmos/azure-cosmos-spark_3_2-12/docs/configuration-reference.md

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing the pip install step:

> pip install azure-cosmos